# Removing entire rows that contain a zero in two Pandas series

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a function which plots the log of two columns from a `Pandas` `DataFrame`. As such zeros cause an error and need to be removed. At the moment the input to the function is two columns from a `DataFrame`. Is there a way to remove any rows containing zeros? For example an equivalent version of df = df[df.ColA != 0]

```
def logscatfit(x,y,title):
    xvals2 = np.arange(-2,6,1)
    a = np.log(x) #These are what I want to remove the zeros from
    b = np.log(y)
    plt.scatter(a, b, c='g', marker='x', s=35)
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(a,b)
    plt.plot(xvals2, (xvals2*slope + intercept), color='red')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
    print "Slope is:",slope, ". Intercept is:",intercept,". R-value is:",r_value,". P-value is:",p_value,". Std_err is:",std_err
```

At can't think of a way of removing the zeros in both `a` and `b` but keeping them the same length so that I can plot a scatter graph. Is my only option to rewrite the function to take a `DataFrame` and then remove the zeros with something like `df1 = df[df.ColA != 0]` then `df2 = df1[df1.ColB != 0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you need to remove rows where **either** (and/or) `x` or `y` are zero.

A simple approach is

```
keepThese = (x > 0) & (y > 0)
a = x[keepThese]
b = y[keepThese]
```

and then proceed with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I like FooBar's answer for simplicity. A more general approach is to pass the dataframe to your function and use the `.any()` method.

```
def logscatfit(df,x_col_name,y_col_name,title):
    two_cols = df[[x_col_name,y_col_name]]
    mask = two_cols.apply(lambda x: ( x==0 ).any(), axis = 1)
    df_to_use = df[mask]
    x = df_to_use[x_col_name]
    y = df_to_use[y_col_name]

    #your code
    a = n.log(x)
    etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting `FooBar`'s answer into your function gives:

```
def logscatfit(x,y,title):
    xvals2 = np.arange(-2,6,1)
    keepThese = (x > 0) & (y > 0)
    a = x[keepThese]
    b = y[keepTheese]        
    a = np.log(a)
    b = np.log(b)
    plt.scatter(a, b, c='g', marker='x', s=35)
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(a,b)
    plt.plot(xvals2, (xvals2*slope + intercept), color='red')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
    print "Slope is:",slope, ". Intercept is:",intercept,". R-value is:",r_value,". P-value is:",p_value,". Std_err is:",std_err
```